# VBA Macro help, Inserting Row and Paste Special Formula

Tags: excel, vba

All,

I would greatly appreciate if someone could assist me with my VBA code Macro.  I have 2 different Macros and I need to combine them AND alter one.

Im inserting a row via Excel at the bottom of the Table ABOVE my "Total Row".  That works fine!!!

```
Sub InsertingRow()

Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

End Sub
```

Then:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("F12:O12").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("F13").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _

        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

**I need to combine the 2 Macros, but I need the PasteSpecial Macro to increment down with the Insert Row Macro and keep the specific columns/cells its copying too as well.

I have a "Total Row" so I need it to push the Total row down and insert/copy in the one above it.

Im sure this is easy.**

Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: Update your post to show us your attempt combining the two macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you on the right track.  I am not sure where your data needs to be copied from but give this a try and you will see how it works.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Rows(lastRow).Insert

    Range("F" & lastRow - 1 & ":O" & lastRow - 1).Copy
    Range("F" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I adjusted the code to do so.  This is assuming you have data in column A that ends on the same row as the table in columns F-O

Comment: My apologies.  I meant to put that I need it right above my "Total" Row in my table.  I adjusted my original post.  Id still take some help please.

Comment: This works on mine.  If the total row is row 12, is there data in cell A12?